# how do i look for duplicate values (username,password) in login database in java?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

So, i have a login form that gets Username and Password. The data for these are stored in a Postgre table i made called useraccounts.

Is there a way to send an error whenever a user inputs a duplicate data in the login form?

For example, if my useraccounts has 
username ｜｜ password
admin         pass
guest         password
admin         pass

how do i just show an error that you cant log in,if you want to enter as admin?

Comment: `if (name is in db) { show error }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use follow behavior.

Column "UserName" should have type citext. It give you a simple search.

Execute query

```
Select username from users where username='user name'
```

or

```
Select username from users where username=?
```

if you can use [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Than you check a result of query execution. If ResultSet is not empty this mean that user with name "user name" already exist and you can provide error.